# What is the event fires when customer logged in and initialize the cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, shopping-cart

What event is fire when initialize the shopping cart just after the customer logged in? This event should set the remained cart items as well as the grand total and subtotal for that cart.

Can anyone suggest the event please?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you want to do? You can use checkout_quote_load_after, collect_totals_before/after and a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various events during logging in and shopping cart initialization.

You can put the following in the function `dispatchEvent` in `Mage.php` to find out which events are dispatched:

```
file_put_contents('/var/log/events.log',"$name \n",FILE_APPEND);
```

This list will get long so it might be clever to start logging right before you log in and stop logging afterwards. That makes it easier to obtain the available events.

Answer (score 3):

When the customer logs in, the `customer_login` event is dispatched. The module `Mage_Checkout` listens to the event and calls the method `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer::loadCustomerQuote()`.

This is where the cart (= quote) is loaded. I don't know what you want to do exactly but I guess this is the place you are searching for.